# Validation Column Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have a Validation Setting column which seems not to be working with the formula `=RTW>=StartDate` and I get error:

> 'Something went Wrong'

However it works if I have the formula `=RTW=>Today()` it does work, How can I get the validation be `ColumA=>ColumnB`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add reference to other columns under **Column Validation** settings.

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

[image]

---

**Updated from Comments**:

Use below formula in list validation settings:

```
=AND([EndDate] >= [StartDate], [RTW] >= [StartDate])
```

Comment: I already have =[EndDate]>=[StartDate] in this validation, can I combine both? if so which formula is correct as always get confused with the IF/AND/OR logic. Also why would the validation within the column not work? what kind of validation can be used in the column?

Comment: In Column validations, you cannot add reference to other columns. For updated formula, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!