# List validation if then syntax

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

I am trying to use list validation to enforce that the value in the Category choice column is compatible with a value in the Activity choice column (1:1)

```
If [Activity] = "Walking"; [Category] = "Exercise"
```

i.e. any choice in Activity that is not Walking is not equal to Exercise.

I'd have thought this easy, but not for me.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? You want to force user to select "Exercise" in Category when user selects "Walking" in Activity OR something else?

Comment: If Walking has been chosen in Activity, only Exercise can be chosen in Category

Comment: Sorry, should have added no OR needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using list validation formula like below:

```
If([Activity] = "Walking", If([Category] = "Exercise", true, false), true)
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

**Similar thread**: [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Many thanks Ganesh - greatly appreciated!