# Sharepoint validation list conditional

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, validation

I need to write a list validation formula. I have a column named type of change that is numbers that is mandatory if other column dollars is filled.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use **List Validation** formula like below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Dollars]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([Type of change]),FALSE,TRUE))
```

Use steps given in this thread to add list validation formula: [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display* names of your columns in the formula.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Did Ganesh Sanaps' answer help you?