# Microsoft LISTS Validation Settings question

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

In my list I have 3 columns, one titled  'Review Status', one titled 'Type of System' and one titled 'Needed Information'.

I am trying to write a validation that says

If the Review Status equals Permit Issued AND the Type of System is Null/Blank then display the error message.

OR

If the Review Status equals 'Additional Information Required' and the 'Needed Information' field is Null/Blank then display the error message.

We don't want to allow the permit to be issued if staff doesn't enter the type of system.  And we don't want staff to sign off the reiew as 'Additional Information Required' if they don't tell us what additional information is required.  Can someone please help me with the Formula?  I have tried quite a few different ways.

Comment: What is the data/column type of all these columns?

Comment: Thank for your reply, they are all picklist fields.

Answer (score 0):

A Microsoft List is just a SharePoint list, so you could use SharePoint column validation. You can find more information about column validation in the link below:

[How to do column validation in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-do-column-validation-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you will have to use the list validation settings and not the column validation settings.

If all your columns are of type single selection choice columns, use list validation formula like below:

```
=IF(AND([Review Status]="Permit",ISBLANK([Type of System])),FALSE,IF(AND([Review Status]="Additional Information Required",ISBLANK([Needed Information])),FALSE,TRUE))
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings. Follow steps given here: [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))