# Validate an entry is within a range

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

Any help with this would be really appreciated!

I have 2 columns both of type number (`OrigDensity` and `TestDensity`).  I would like to validate as a user inputs `TestDensity` it must be +/- 0.05 of `OrigDensity` (i.e. data from same row).

From online readings, the following approach appears best but just am struggling with syntax I think.

I am using:

```
IF ([TestDensity] >= ([OrigDensity] - 0.05), AND [TestDensity] <= ([OriginalDensity] + 0.05) ,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of both the columns are required in your SharePoint list, try using below simple formula in **List validation** settings:

```
=AND([TestDensity] >= ([OrigDensity] - 0.05),[TestDensity] <= ([OrigDensity] + 0.05))
```

You can find the detailed steps to add list validation formula in my answer at: [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

---

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

Comment: Suggested formula works - thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Please [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Keep using this platform for asking any questions related to SharePoint, thank you!