# SharePoint List - Column Validation

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula, date-time, column-validation, list-validation

I want to write 2 formula to validate below conditions:

I have 3 columns in SharePoint list:

1. Date of Booster (Date field)
2. Is resident in Hospice? (Yes/No Field)
3. Date Admission at Hospice (Date Field)

1st formula:  User must enter a date > 9/1/2021 to validate the date must be greater than 9/1/2021 in [Date of Booster] field

2nd formula :  If user selects Yes in [Is resident in Hospice], they must be enter the admission date which it needs to be later than 9/1/2021 in [Date Admission at Hospice]

Answer (score 0):

For first condition, use **column level validation** on "Date of Booster" field. Use formula:

```
=[Date of Booster] > DATE(2021,9,1)
```

For second condition, use **list level validation**. Use formula:

```
=IF([Is resident in Hospice?], IF(ISBLANK([Date Admission at Hospice]), false, IF([Date Admission at Hospice] > DATE(2021,9,1), true, false)), true)
```

Reference of similar thread for list validation steps: [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Hello Ganesh, the first formula is working, but the 2nd formula returned with syntax error.

Comment: Where are you adding second formula? Remember you have to add it to list validation settings and not column validation settings of "[Date Admission at Hospice]" column. Also, make sure you are using correct names of your columns.

Comment: Yes, I have added 2nd formula in List Validation Setting rather than column validation level. After I have added 2nd formula in List Validation Setting successfully, it crashed with 1st formula in [Date of Booster] field.  It returned "evaluated error " when I entered the date >9/1/2021

Comment: What were the values of other two columns when this error occurred?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, for 1st formula =[Date of Booster] > DATE(2021,9,1) ,  this [Date of Booster] is an optional field which this field can be blank.  I need help to have a revise formula for to validate  [Date of Booster] when user enter the date.  User could not save the entry without entering date because I have used =[Date of Booster] > DATE(2021,9,1)

Comment: Try using: `IF(ISBLANK([Date of Booster]), true, [Date of Booster] > DATE(2021,9,1))`

Comment: Hi @CarrieWong does this help you? If yes, please [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.