# List Validation syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, validation, list-validation

I have a challenge with the List Validation process for a simple form. I need to check 2 fields: If `[NPC Status]` is "Passed" and `[NPC End Date]` greater or equal 2/24/2022.

```
=IF([NPC Status]="Passed",IF([NPC End Date]>=DATEVALUE("2/24/2022"),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

When I click the Ok button, the error message appears: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

What is wrong with my formula? In Excel it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF([NPC Status] = "Passed", IF([NPC End Date] >= DATE(2022, 2, 24), TRUE, FALSE), TRUE)
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

**Similar thread**: [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My region in SP is Ukraine, so I replaced all commas with semicolons and code started to work properly.