# SharePoint Online Modern Form Conditional Formatting (Column Rules)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, json-formatting, validation

I am working on a SharePoint Online Modern Form solution using the OTB conditional formatting. There are three rules that I am trying to apply, here is the example.

Two Columns:

1. COL1 - Choice Field - Yes, No
2. COL2 - Single Line of Text

The rule is: If you choose 'Yes' for COL1 then you have to fill out COL2

I currently have: =if([$COL1],'true','false'). This conditional formatting works to hide/show COL2 when COL1 = Yes.

Here is what I'm looking to accomplish:

1. If you choose 'Yes' in Col1, COL2 becomes REQUIRED.
2. If you choose 'No' in COL1, COL2 must be NULL/Blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the SharePoint **List validation** settings for your requirements.

Use list validation formula like:

```
=IF([Col1] = "Yes", NOT(ISBLANK([Col2])), IF([Col1] = "No", ISBLANK([Col2]), TRUE))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

You can find the steps to add list validation formula in below threads:

**Similar threads**:

1. [How to have validation for calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280477/how-to-have-validation-for-calculated-column/280480#280480)
2. [List Validation syntax error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302079/list-validation-syntax-error/302080#302080)
3. [SharePoint list validation formula issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309223/sharepoint-list-validation-formula-issue/309224#309224)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you