# Making required condition in SharePoint list dependent on another field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have a SharePoint list with several choice, date, text and yes/no fields. I want to make some fields conditional on another field containing a certain word.

So for example, I have a field called 'Status' (a choice column) that has the choices: In progress, Completed, Finalised.

I have a second field (a date column) called 'End date' and I want that field to be required only when the Status is Finalised.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the SharePoint **List validation** settings for your requirements.

Use list validation formula like:

```
=IF([Status]="Finalised",NOT(ISBLANK([End date])),TRUE)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.
4. For more complex validation and rules, you will have to customize the list form using Power Apps and apply validation using Power Apps formulas. Check: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form).

You can find the steps to add list validation formula in below threads:

**Similar threads**:

1. [How to have validation for calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280477/how-to-have-validation-for-calculated-column/280480#280480)
2. [List Validation syntax error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302079/list-validation-syntax-error/302080#302080)
3. [SharePoint list validation formula issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309223/sharepoint-list-validation-formula-issue/309224#309224)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! What if I want to use multiple values in the formula? So for example, if the 'Status' is either Completed or Finalised then both the 'End date' column as well as another column called 'Signed By' becomes required.

Comment: Try something like: `=IF(OR([Status]="Finalised",[Status]="Finalised"),AND(NOT(ISBLANK([End date])),NOT(ISBLANK([Signed By]))),TRUE)`

Comment: If signed by column is of type person or group, it is not possible to use such columns in SharePoint formulas. You will have to customize the list form using Power Apps for such complex Column types and complex validation rules.