# List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, formula

I've tried a plethora of solutions from other posts, however I am having no luck.

I would like to make FieldA, FieldB, and FieldC required if Dropdown1 is set to 'WON' when creating an item in my SharePoint list, meaning the item cannot be saved until FieldA, FieldB, and FieldC contain some information.

What formula would I use in List validation to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF([Dropdown1]="WON", IF(OR(ISBLANK([FieldA]), ISBLANK([FieldC]), ISBLANK([FieldC])), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

**Related threads**:

1. [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)
2. [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

Comment: Oh Wow! Amazing, thank you so much this worked perfectly!!