# Two formulas in validation settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I am trying to add two formulas in validation settings but getting syntax errors.

I have created a leave request list in SharePoint. My requirements are below:

If Half Day(Yes/No column) is equal to Yes, then AM or PM(choice column) should be mandatory.
If Type Of Leave(Choice column) is equal to Time Off, then Number of Hours(Number Column) should be mandatory.

Need help to put the above two conditions in 1 formula. Sorry I am not a technical person so trying to work around the requirements here.

Also I don’t know how and where to enter code if that’s the solution. I was trying to enter formula. If that’s the solution, it’s the best. So if you can provide a step by step guide.

Comment: Can you add the formula you are using currently to your question?

Comment: =IF([Type of Leave]="Time Off",IF(ISBLANK([Number Of Hours]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)

Comment: Above is one formula I am using and it’s working… I don’t know how to add another one to this

Comment: check my answer given below. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much… works perfectly fine… :)

Comment: I have one more question… I have a multiple lines of text column called “Reason”… can I make that mandatory too to specify timings if anyone selects time off?

Comment: You cannot use multiple lines of text columns in validation formula in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula in **List validation** settings:

```
=AND(IF([Type of Leave]="Time Off",IF(ISBLANK([Number Of Hours]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE), IF([Half Day],IF(ISBLANK([AM or PM]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE))
```

Follow my answer given in below thread to add formula in **List validation** settings: [List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304367/list-validation-to-make-multiple-fields-mandatory-if-dropdown-meets-condition/304369#304369)

Comment: Amazing… works perfectly fine… Thank you so much 

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!