# How date can be dependent on status changing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, json-formatting, validation

I developed a travel plan list on SharePoint. In the plan, for travel, there are 3 drop-down stages:

- Planned
- Completed
- Cancelled

But the issue is anyone can select the "Completed" status without planning a trip. Which is now became a massive issue.

By the way, I used a validation formula under validation settings and this logic is necessary:

```
=AND([Planned End Date]>=[Planned Start Date],[Actual End Date]>=[Actual Start Date])
```

Now, I need an idea to set a new logic.

1. How it is possible if someone chooses the "Completed" option the logic will check whether s/he is "Planned" or not? If the travel is not "Planned" in advance, the system will restrict him/her to save it.
2. Also is there a way, if someone plans a trip and selected a date for this trip, s/he will get an auto-generated email that you have to change your status to "Completed" if the planned date expired? Here JSON code will play a vital role if you have any idea.

Any ideas or suggestions on JSON coding or other option?

Comment: 1. What conditions are required (based on dates or status) to check if the  trip was previously planned or not? 2. You cannot send automated emails using JSON formatting.  You will have to use the Power automate flow or [Rules in SharePoint lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/27/rules-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/).

Comment: Thanks. In the list, 3 status are there, planned, completed, & cancel. If status is "Planned" then "Planned Start Date" and "Planned End Date" will pop up. If "Completed" then "Actual Start Date" and "Actual End Date" will pop up. But the issue, anyone can select "Completed" status without planned a trip in advance. Now my query is, if someone select "Completed" status it should be checked whether "Planned Start Date" and "Planned End Date" is there or not. If not, the form automatically deny to save it's status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula in List Validation settings formula:

```
=IF(AND([Status]="Completed",OR(ISBLANK([Planned Start Date]),ISBLANK([Planned End Date]))),FALSE,AND([Planned End Date]>=[Planned Start Date],[Actual End Date]>=[Actual Start Date]))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Two formulas in validation settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304953/two-formulas-in-validation-settings/304955#304955)
2. [List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304367/list-validation-to-make-multiple-fields-mandatory-if-dropdown-meets-condition/304369#304369)

Comment: Amazing. It works perfectly superb. Thank you.

Comment: Hello...one more query in the same list. In the column heading, there is an option named "Totals" and under this "None or Count" drop-down is available. I picked it for the "Status" column. It shows the total count at the bottom of how many were planned/completed/canceled, while I select the filter planned, the column shows the total count of planned travel.

I have a calculated column named "Total Planned Days" It is the difference between "Planned Start Date" and "Planned End Date". I used the below logic. Intentionally I used this formula. Continues.....

Comment: =IF(AND([Planned End Date]>0,[Planned Start Date]>0),[Planned End Date]-[Planned Start Date]+1,"")

But in the "Total Planned Days" column the "Total" option is missing.

The same thing is applied with "Total Actual Days" and there is also the missing "Total" option.

Is there any way to count the total at the bottom?

Comment: Also, can you please [ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for your other queries? Add detailed requirements in the new question. It will easier to track the requirements in separate question and the new question will be open for other community members as well so that they can answer your queries.

Comment: Oh yes, I did. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) the answer as well as it helped you & it will help others  with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.