# SharePoint list validation formula issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

This is the first time asking here. I'm trying to write a formula for list validation but I cannot understand what I'm missing.

For this formula I need to chain 2 conditions

1. `[Start date]<= [End Date]` (both columns are date columns)
2. `AND(ISBLANK([End Date]), [Status] = "Disabled)`

Basically the [End Date] column value should be greater than [Start date] on one hand and on the other the [End date] column must not be empty while the [Status] column's value is "Disabled" ([Status] is a choice with 2 options column).

I came up with the following but apparently there's something wrong with the syntax:

```
=IF(AND([Start Date]<=[End Date],IF(AND(ISBLANK([End Date]), [Status]="Disabled")FALSE,TRUE)FALSE,TRUE)
```

I've checked MS documentation and according to it the formula above should work:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-9ca21054-a466-477e-98bf-fc79e62afb3c
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a

Can you please help me figure this out?

I'm doing this in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in List Validation settings formula:

```
=IF(AND([Status]="Disabled",ISBLANK([End Date])),FALSE,IF([End Date]<[Start Date],FALSE,TRUE))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Two formulas in validation settings](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304953/two-formulas-in-validation-settings/304955#304955)
2. [List validation to make multiple fields mandatory if dropdown meets condition](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304367/list-validation-to-make-multiple-fields-mandatory-if-dropdown-meets-condition/304369#304369)