# Multiple sharepoint list date column validation in list settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, validation, list-validation

I am trying to add validation on multiple dates in SharePoint list.

Example: If end date is added by user the start date shall be mandatory. The start date shall not be greater than end date.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End date]),TRUE,[End date]>=[Start date])
```

This is not working and not making start date mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula for your list validation settings:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End date]),TRUE,AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Start date])),[End date]>=[Start date]))
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

**Related threads**:

1. [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)
2. [List validation if then syntax](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298168/list-validation-if-then-syntax/298171#298171)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (It is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).