# Set field as mandatory if the field is dependent on another field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, validation

Can I set a field as mandatory if the field is dependent on the status?

Below is the form to insert information for a new plan. How to set Purpose of Visit field as mandatory.

[image]

If I use the below condition, it will no longer dependent on status:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the "Purpose of Visit" field mandatory in case the Status field is equal to "Planned" using SharePoint list validation formula.

You can use the SharePoint list validation formula like:

```
=IF([Status]="Planned",IF(ISBLANK([Key Activity/Purpose of Visit]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

**OR**

```
=IF([Status]="Planned",NOT(ISBLANK([Key Activity/Purpose of Visit])),TRUE)
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

**Similar thread**: [Validation Column Not Working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/validation-column-not-working/292527#292527)

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (It is based on language or regional settings of your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Make sure you are using correct *display name* of your columns in the formula

---

**Update from comments**:

Unfortunately, you cannot use Multiple lines of text columns in SharePoint formulas. This is a limitation of SharePoint by design.

In that case, you will have to use the Power Apps customized list form to make the "Key Activity/Purpose of Visit" (multiple lines of text) column mandatory.

**Documentation**: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

Comment: But I have already the below validation

Comment: =IF(AND(Status="Completed",OR(ISBLANK([Planned Start Date]),ISBLANK([Planned End Date]))),FALSE,AND([Planned End Date]>=[Planned Start Date],[Actual End Date]>=[Actual Start Date]))    How I fit the above condition

Comment: Try something like this: `=IF([Status]="Planned",NOT(ISBLANK([Key Activity/Purpose of Visit])),IF(AND([Status]="Completed",OR(ISBLANK([Planned Start Date]),ISBLANK([Planned End Date]))),FALSE,AND([Planned End Date]>=[Planned Start Date],[Actual End Date]>=[Actual Start Date])))`

Comment: I received this message-Sorry, something went wrong

Comment: Any solution dear?

Comment: Are you using the correct names of your columns in the formula?

Comment: Yes, I checked..

Comment: I used the right names

Comment: =IF([Status]="Planned",IF(ISBLANK([Key Activity/Purpose of Visit]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE) OR =IF([Status]="Planned",NOT(ISBLANK([Key Activity/Purpose of Visit])),TRUE) I used both the validation separately as a single validation but it wont work

Comment: Do you get any error while using this validation formula separately or it does not work as expected?

Comment: While I even used it separately I got this text "Sorry, something went wrong"

Comment: Try renaming your column to just "Purpose of Visit" and try using: `=IF([Status]="Planned",IF(ISBLANK([Purpose of Visit]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)`.

Comment: I am sorry but I am facing the same issue

Comment: Strange! Are you adding it in list validation settings or column validation settings? Note: column names in formula are case-sensitive. So, you have to use the exact column names with same capital/small letters.

Comment: I am using list validation setting. I am also a bit surprised why it is happening. Any option to talk to you online? It troubles me a lot

Comment: I figured out the problem. While I was using the validation formula, I received the below error message "Sorry, something went wrong-
One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas." 

"Purpose of Visit" column data type is "Multiple lines of text". Later I created a new column with a different name and selected the data type as "Number" and then the formula worked. 

How can I deal with this, I already received information on this column and the datatype should be "Multiple lines of text"

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use Multiple lines of text columns in SharePoint formulas. This is a limitation of SharePoint by design. Check updated answer.